# Docker container 'Connect ECONNREFUSED localhost'

Tags: node.js, docker, http, docker-compose

I am running a simple Nodejs application with 2 containers. A server container and a client. I have a setup so that when the client makes a request to the server, it streams some data back to the client, however when I try to make this request from the client, I receive the following error

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
```

This is also the case when I use the containers IP address. Both containers are on the same network. I confirmed this with docker network inspect. When I make the same request via Postman, it works fine.

Here is my setup

**Server Setup**

Server Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /home/node/server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Server http function

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    filePath = path.join("./serverdata", 'filename.txt');
    var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    readStream.pipe(response);
})
.listen(port);
```

**Client Setup**

Client Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /home/node/client
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "capp.js"]
```

Client Get Function
**NB** using the server container IP yielded same results

```
http.get('http://localhost:8080', (resp)=>{
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk)=>{
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.end('end', ()=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
}).on("error", (err)=>{
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Docker Compose

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  server-app:
    build: ./serverClient
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - servervol:/serverdata

  client-app:
    build: ./clientClient
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - clientvol:/clientdata
    depends_on:
      - "server-app"

volumes:
  servervol:
    driver: local
  clientvol:
    driver: local
```

I have read a few posts proclaiming that the issue is with using localhost instead of the container IP, but I have tried both with no success. As mentioned, when done in Postman, it works fine; this leads me to think that the issue is with the client part. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `server-app:8080` instead of `localhost`? It's preferable to use container names instead of IP addresses.

Comment: @StefanGolubović Hmm. So chaning from the ip/localhost to the container name now no longer shows a refused connection, but now says that resp.end() is not a function.

Comment: Just an addition to my previous reply. I got rid of resp.end and changed it to a return statement and no error occurs! However I have a new problem where the contents of the txt file aren't in the client :/

Comment: Maybe `resp.on('end', () => { ... })` will work instead of `resp.end('end', () => { ... })`.

Comment: @StefanGolubović It worked! Thank you so much. I am fairly new to Stack Overflow. Am I able to mark your replies as an answer?

Comment: No, but I can write an answer and then you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using Docker Compose, by default (because you didn't specify network) your services share the [same (default) network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), and therefore you can use the name of the service instead of its IP address to communicate with it because Docker can figure out the IP address based on service name due to service name resolution.

And because of all that Docker magic, the only thing you need to change is the way you connect to server:

```js
http.get('server-app:8080', (resp) => { ... })
```